# rails - postgres trigger action with a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, triggers, database-trigger

I'm creating a new rails APP that's works with the same postgres DB as my API.

The API and the APP has a couples of common models.

---

Exemple :

The API and the APP has a `Connection` model

The APP will create a simple `connection` in the DB and the API will do the rest (like handler using the `connection` for many things )

---

So I wanted to use [Hair Trigger](https://github.com/jenseng/hair_trigger) that allowed to trigger a DB insert, or update and like it to a DB behavior that's will be execute.

But I would like to execute a method from one of my helpers.

like that :

```
class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base

 trigger.after(:insert) do
   SomeObject.method()    
 end

end
```

I can't use `after_create` because the creation action is not done on the same server (but same DB)

any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: so what the problem with using that gem?

Comment: it's seems to only takes SQL string between the do ... end statments
But I would like to pass a call to a method (with the object inserted)

Comment: I am also looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Hair Trigger only supports SQL is that it's purpose is to help you maintain database triggers (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtrigger.html).

Database triggers are decoupled from your application and will only be able to trigger SQL inside your database. *It won't actually be able to trigger any code inside of your application.*

A solution to your problem would be to use events. If you ever worked with Javascript you might have come across Event and EventListener before. The purpose of events is to decouple your code. One part of your application *sends an event* when an action has been taken e.g. **Something was inserted into the database**. Other parts, as many as you like, of your application can then *subscribe* to these events and take the actions necessary.

Since you are working with Rails I would suggest you to take a closer look at the Wisper gem (github.com/krisleech/wisper). If your App and API; like you are describing, lives in different processes (or servers), you should look into using a background worker to handle the events asynchronously. A common approach to this is to use Sidekiq Wisper (github.com/krisleech/wisper-sidekiq) that enables you to trigger the events async using Sidekiq as your background worker.

For a good introduction to the subject, here's a guide to get you started (I'm not the author): http://www.g9labs.com/2016/06/23/rails-pub-slash-sub-with-wisper-and-sidekiq/

There might be easier ways to solve the issue you are facing but you will need to post some more details on the use case for us to give you some better pointers.